# Spring Boot application, running on WAS 9, eventually fails to connect to DB2 database

Tags: spring, db2, websphere

We have a spring boot application, deployed to WAS 9. It uses JPA connection. The UI triggers a background process that reads and writes data to one DB2 database using JPA. The application eventually encounters a database connection error:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection
Caused by: java.sql.SQLTransientConnectionException: HikariPool-1 - Connection is not available, request timed out after 120002ms.
```

The database remains available, the resources on the WAS and DB servers are within the operable range when this exception happens (CPU, RAM, DISK, Heap and Thread count are all good)

Initially the application selects 6000 records that it then loops through and creates related records in other tables. This process works without any issues  outside of WebSphere. The issue occurs after a certain number of records has been processed. Always at the same point of progress. If we reduce the initial number of selected records then we can get further, but eventually the application will fail with the same error as above.

I am wondering what resource limit or constraint could we be encountering on the WAS server?

Answer (score 0):

Smells like a connection leak. Or too many connections being open and held at the same time.

Its also possible that the WAS config is different from the BOOT config.